# How can I get updated value of email from AuthController class and show it in drawer in Flutter using GetX?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I am trying to get the controller value in another class which is email, in Sign in class I have Texteditingcontroller of email and trying to get the updated value of email to show in drawer,  but can't get updated value from Authcontroller class.

```
import 'package:eparkingsystem/view/screens/user/home/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:eparkingsystem/view/screens/user/profile/profile.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../view/screens/user/auth/signin.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
  //with instance AuthController would be able to the app everywhere
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();
  late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;



  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    //our user would be notified
    _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
    ever(_user, _initialScreen);
  }

  _initialScreen(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print("Home Screen for Login");
      Get.offAllNamed('/home');
    } else {
      Get.offAllNamed('/profile');
    }
  }

  void register(String email, password) async {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      Get.snackbar("Account Created",
          "Please sign in, Account is successfully registered",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
          icon: Icon(Icons.login),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));
      Get.toNamed('/signin');
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "weak-password") {
        Get.snackbar("Re-Enter Password", "Password is weak",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
            icon: Icon(Icons.login),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));
        print("Password is Weak");
      } else if (e.code == "email-already-in-use") {
        Get.snackbar("Alert!", "Email already Registered",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
            icon: Icon(Icons.login),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));
        print("Email already Registered");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("About User", e.toString(),
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          titleText: Text(
            "Account creation failed",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          messageText:
              Text(e.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)));
    }
  }

  void login(String email, password) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      Get.snackbar("Logged In", "Successfully Logged In",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
          icon: Icon(Icons.login),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));
      Get.toNamed('/profile');
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
        Get.snackbar("Account Error",
            "Account has been suspended by Admin, Credentials not Found, or maybe deleted by user",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
            icon: Icon(Icons.login),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));
        print(
            "Account has been suspended by Admin, Credentials not Found, or maybe deleted by user");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Exception Occured", e.toString(),
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          titleText: Text(
            "Login failed",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          messageText:
              Text(e.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)));
      print("hello");
    }
  }

  void logOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
    Get.snackbar(
        "Account Logged Out", "You've Successfully Logged Out from Account",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
        icon: Icon(Icons.login),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0));
  }
}
```

I've tried to add obs with variable but didn't get the value of Email from this authcontroller class, how can I get that value to show?